# Is $_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'] considered 'safe'?

Tags: php, apache, authentication, iis, cgi

The [CGI specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3875#section-4.1.11) defines the `REMOTE_USER` server attribute, which contains the name of the authenticated user.

For example, on Apache, this might be provided via .htpasswd authentication, whereas on IIS it might be handled via Active Directory.  In either case, the web server handles the authentication and then passes the name of the authenticated user back to PHP if authentication was successful.  (If unsuccessful or cancelled, the script will never run.)

My question: Can we rely on this variable?  i.e. if it is present (and non-blank, I guess) is it safe to assume that the authentication has been successfully passed and that the supplied name is the name used to authenticate?

In particular, I am worried about whether there is a possibility to inject this server property into my PHP script in situations where authentication did not take place, or to spoof the value so it contains something other than the username that passed the authentication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can we rely on this variable?

Yes, to the extent that you can rely on the proper configuration of your server.

> I am worried about whether there is a possibility to inject this server property into my PHP script

It can be spoofed, but only from the server side. E.g., via a .htaccess line like:

```
SetEnv REMOTE_USER foo
```

Or directly in PHP like:

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER'] = 'foo';
```

So, if your attacker can remotely change your .htaccess files or your PHP source, then userid spoofing is the least of your problems.